# Loading multiple images from url to android application using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso, android-webservice

I have implemented an android application aiming at the visualization of the images received through web services. I am parsing the JSON data received from the web service in order to receive the url from where I will load the image. 
Then I want to load those images to an imageview using Picasso, though I always receive the error below:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.user.sugardraft, PID: 21592
>                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.sugardraft/com.example.user.sugardraft.GalleryActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.

The activity file is:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
String url = "https://..../wp-json/wp/v2/media";
List<Object> list;
Gson gson;
ListView postList;
GridView gridView;
GridAdapter myGridAdapter;

Map<String,Object> mapPost;
Map<String,Object> mapTitle;
int postID;
String postTitle[];
ImageView imageView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            gson = new Gson();
            list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
            postTitle = new String[list.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
                mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) list.get(i);
                mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("guid");
                postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
                Log.d("Value", "Value: " + postTitle[i].toString());
                Picasso.get().load(postTitle[i]).into(imageView);
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Activity.this);
    rQueue.add(request);

}
```

And the .xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.user.sugardraft.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/fotologo2"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"> 
 </ImageView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Could you please help me? Is there any other way in order to load all the images received form the web service in a gallery?

Answer (score 0):

The `Target` refers to the `imageView` that you pass to `into`. Your `imageView` ids do not correspond, in your `onCreate` you bind it to `R.id.imageview`, but such an id doesn't exist in the XML file that you provided. Instead in `onCreate` put `R.id.imageView_gallery`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @LieForBananas. I have updated the code above and so the code on my application. Though I am having the same error again. Any ideas please?

Comment: So it's still the problem with the imageView, try to change the id in the XML to something unique like `android:id="@+id/imageViewNew"` and change it in your activity as well when you do `findViewById`.

Comment: I have made the change and now the error is
Process: com.example.user.test, PID: 25181
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                                                 at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:682)

Comment: @MariaTsourma so you changed in XML to `android:id="@+id/imageViewNew" ` and in `onCreate` to `imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewNew);` ?